# remove black background from ion-tab-bar ionic 7

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework

i am working on an ionic 7 project, here i have a navigation guide with 4 tabs

i want to style the iontabs now and have added custom css.

i get a black background although the area should be transparent.

i have a similar problem to a question before me that i took as a reference, however the solution did not help me here ([remove white background from ion-tab-bar ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59682805/remove-white-background-from-ion-tab-bar-ionic-4)).

html:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <div class="tabs-inner"></div>
  <div  style="background-color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0 ;">

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">

      <ion-tab-button tab="race">
        <ion-icon name="map-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button tab="favoriten">
        <ion-icon name="bookmarks-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button tab="start">
        <ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button tab="me">
        <ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>

</div>

</ion-tabs>
```

css:

```
ion-tab-bar{
  //position: absolute;

  --background: rgba(255,255,255,5);
  border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right :15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow:
  0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.04),
  0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
  flex: 1;
  position: unset !important;
}

.tabs-inner {
  position: relative;
  //flex: 1;
  contain: layout size style;
}
```

i have also added the following to global.scss unfortunately without success

```
.tabs-inner {
  position: unset !important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have the background to black, thats why.....

```
ion-tab-bar{
  background-color: black;
}
```

It needs to be transparent.

```
ion-tab-bar{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: dont remove the error :(

Comment: @du7ri Try  `background-color: transparent;`